# Xen: graphics passthrough. How it looks from the host?

Tags: graphics-card, virtualization, xen

I'm starting to think to install Xen as a main hypervisor; and I need to have a single Win7 client with access to (primary, single) physical GPU with accelerated graphics support.

Now, am I right with this: when that client starts, it takes over Dom0's graphic display, because Dom0 has no more access to that card? Does it returns the card back to Dom0 after shutting down? Can Dom0 session resume work with that card? When can I expect hangs?

---

Cards in question:

- GT5x0
- laptop's integrated HD7xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you have two graphics adapters, not only one.

The host uses the integrated GPU, you have to tell it to reserve the other for the guest. Since you hide the other GPU from the host, you cannot use it at all in the host. This reservation, to prevent the host doing anything with the second GPU, is done at boot; I don't think it's possible to hotplug/unplug the PCI device in the host.

On the other hand, you should be able to have two guests, and alternate the GPU between the two, as long as only one of the guest is actually booted.